# How should I disable wave animation

Tags: battery, 5.1-lollipop

I have seen in my device running Lollipop that, when charges get below 15% the device get into **Battery Saver mode**, in which all the animation of the Android get disabled (like, Wave animation).
So, I just wanted to disable that animation manually, how can I do that, anyone know please share it.

**Note:**  I have rooted phone

Answer (score 0):

You could try  setting the animation scale to 0% (in developer options)

If it is not enabled already, go to Settings > About phone and then tap Build number seven times.

After that Settings > Developer options will be available.

In the developer mode and set animation scale to .0% (or off)

Credits:  [Disable Animations on Lollipop](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/2o37y3/disable_animations_on_lollipop/)